# Replace a string in cell array into 1x3 numeric cell array

Tags: matlab

Cell array data as below:

```
data=

'A' [0.006] 'B'
'C' [3.443] 'C'
```

i would like to convert character in first column in to 1x3 vector, mean that

- 'A' replace by [0] [0] [0],
- 'C' replace by [0] [1] [0]..

the result will be

```
[0] [0] [0] [0.006] 'B'
[0] [1] [0] [3.443] 'C'
```

the code i tried as below:

```
B=data(1:end,1);
B=regexprep(B,'C','[0 0 0]');
B=regexprep(B,'A','[0 1 0]');
```

the result show me

```
B=

'[0 0 0]'
'[0 1 0]'
```

which is wrong, each character does not change to 1x3 array...please help...

Comment: What are the rules for converting letters to three numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify the rule to convert letters to numbers,
I assumed you want to replace `A` with `000`, `B` with `001`, ..., `H` with `111`
(ie numbers from 0 to 7 in binary, corresponding to letters A to H).

In case you want to go up to Z, the code below can be easily changed.

```
%# you data cell array
data = {
    'A' [0.006] 'B'
    'C' [3.443] 'C'
};

%# compute binary numbers equivalent to letters A to H
binary = num2cell(dec2bin(0:7)-'0');      %# use 0:25 to go up to Z

%# convert letters in to row indices in the above cell array "binary"
idx = cellfun(@(c) c-'A'+1, upper(data(:,1)));

%# replace first column, and build new data
newData = [binary(idx,:) data(:,2:end)]
```

The result:

```
newData = 
    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0.006]    'B'
    [0]    [1]    [0]    [3.443]    'C'
```